# Invalid skip forward/backward icons in CarPlay for specific intervals

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

I'm trying to develop Now playing screen in CarPlay and I've some issues with visual representation of buttons connected with commands `skipForwardCommand`/`skipBackwardCommand`

When I set property `preferredIntervals` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpskipintervalcommand/1622899-preferredintervals?language=objc)) to standard intervals like 10, 15, 30, 60, then everything looks fine.

When I try to use different values - for instance 5, 120 then instead of skip forward/backward icon I can see next/previous track (button still works like skip forward/backward it only has bad visual representation).
It works properly in iPhone notification center - instead of custom values you can see here skip forward button with plus and skip backward button with minus.

`nextTrackCommand` and `previousTrackCommand` are disabled in code.

I've seen earlier one app, which have custom intervals and has got in such case skip forward/backward icons but without any value (empty).
I would like to achieve the same or similar effect.

On the attached screen, on the skip backward I've used value of 5 seconds, on the right side - standard value 30 seconds.
[image: CarPlay Now playing view]

Comment: Can you name the app that has custom steps with buttons that render empty skip seconds icons?

Comment: It's polish app called Audioteka

Comment: I downloaded the app. When I set the skip seconds backwards interval to 5s the behavior is the same as in your screenshot: the skip to previous track button is visible

Comment: Well, that's strange. In general it looks like an Apple bug. Right know I've decided to use next/previous chapter button in this place and use custom buttons for my functionality in this section under seekbar. It works very well with such combination.

Comment: Yeah I use the same functionality but let the user decide which buttons are the primary ones (next to the play button) and which should be smaller in the custom buttons area. Since I only have default skip intervals they render fine next to the play button.